# How do you enable cross-origin requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to enable CORS on an API built with ASP.NET Core MVC, but all the current documents refer to earlier versions of that framework.

Comment: How about this? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: As documented in the "new" docs here: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html and http://mvc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security/cors-policy.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The notes on the new Cors features are very light, but I was able to get it working in my solution by looking at the new classes and methods. My Web API **startup.cs** looks like this. You can see how you can construct your origins and policies her by using the new `CorsPolicy` class. And enabling CORS with the `AddCors` and `UseCors` methods.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddMvc();
     //Add Cors support to the service
     services.AddCors();

     var policy = new Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core.CorsPolicy();

     policy.Headers.Add("*");    
     policy.Methods.Add("*");          
     policy.Origins.Add("*");
     policy.SupportsCredentials = true;

     services.ConfigureCors(x=>x.AddPolicy("mypolicy", policy));

 }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment  env)
 {
     // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

     app.UseStaticFiles();
     //Use the new policy globally
     app.UseCors("mypolicy");
     // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
     app.UseMvc();
 }
```

You can also reference the policy in the controllers with the new attributes like so

```
[EnableCors("mypolicy")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

Comment: Just a note, I had to add `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` to my project.json for this to work, more specifically the `app.UseCors("mypolicy");` line reported an error untill that package was added. In my case I used version `1.0.0-beta6` (instead of the final `5.2.3` version also available.). Also, it is important to add `using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;` to `Startup.cs` if it's not already there.

Comment: Just a note for people... it didn't work for me until I realized I had to put the UseCors before the UseMvc line.

Answer (score 19):

I got it working using the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()));
}
```

You can chain `AllowAnyHeader()` and/or `AllowAnyMethod()` to the configure action if needed.

To configure it for the complete app:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
}
```

Or just for a controller:

```
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

--

**Update:** configuring CORS for *all* requests can be done a bit easier:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://some.origin.com")
               .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
}
```

For more information, refer to the [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html).

Answer (score 8):

In the most recent `RC2` of ASP.NET Core.

The NuGet packages are

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
```

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseCors(builder =>  builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin());
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: If a browser uses a pre-flight request (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html#preflight-requests) you need also to set allowed headers and methods: `app.UseCors(_ => _.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod())`

Answer (score 3):

Support for CORS is currently in development. Following issue is tracking that:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/498

**Update (3/28/2015)**:
This feature has been checked in and should be available in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

cs1929 the method services.ConfigureCors(...) does no more exist. It is combined to AddCors:

```
services.AddCors(options => 
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Install : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors

In Configure method:

```
        app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins("http://some.origin.com"));
```