# Enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in ASP.Net 5 / Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I add CORS headers to my MVC6 application? I am interested in Globally and per action.

It seems like ASP.Net vNext/5/Core has undergone some changes so there are different answers to this question for different versions. I'm using RC1.

I have tried this SO "[How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-5)", but coming to `var policy = new Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core.CorsPolicy();` the "Core" namespace does not exist.

Tried the answer in "[How do you enable cross-origin requests (CORS) in ASP.NET 5 & MVC 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100538/how-do-you-enable-cross-origin-requests-cors-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)" but the method/extension method`services.ConfigureCors` does not exist.

The last SO answer is the same as [this blog post](https://neelbhatt40.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/what-is-cors-and-how-to-enable-it-in-asp-net-5vnext/), which also says to first install Microsoft.AspNet.Cors (`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Cors`). But doing so makes things worse, then `services.AddCors()` doesn't exist for some reason.

"[Enable cross-origin requests (CORS) in ASP.NET 5 & MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851028/enable-cross-origin-requests-cors-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)" says to install "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core" which does not exist, and `using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;` which doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: Try to add `services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyHeader()));` in `ConfigureServices` method and `app.UseCors("AllowAll");` in `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`. You should add `"Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "6.0.0-rc1-final"` to `"dependencies"` of `project.json`. See [the documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html?highlight=cors)

Comment: That works. As per the the instructions on the blog post it was installing version 5.2.3 of Microsoft.AspNet.Cors, needed version 6.0.0.

Comment: It's a large problem which have many developers now. The packages will be renames and the requests to the old names will be not redirected. I posted [the suggestion](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1222), but it seems that Microsoft don't see the problem serious enough. By the way the package is renames now to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors](https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors). :-)

Comment: Quite a moving target this CORS. Thanks Oleg, useful to know. So it will probably change once again in next release then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the prerelease version:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Cors -PreRelease
```

Add the following under ConfigureServices in your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowFromAll",
        builder => builder
        .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

If you want to add it globally, put this under configure:

```
app.UseCors("AllowFromAll");
```

If you want it per controller/action you can decorate them with the following:

```
[EnableCors("AllowFromAll")]
```

There's a lot more info in the docs regarding cors, for your reference:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core 1.0 release I had to add the following to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs in order to get global CORS configuration to work globally and without attributes:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowFromAll")); 
});

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowFromAll", builder => builder
        .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```