# How can I call a rest service from a Blazor app

Tags: rest, blazor

After creating a default Blazor app (V0.5.1) we get a FetchData.cshtml page which gets its data from a local .json file

```
@functions {
    WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
    }

    class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works fine. However, if change this to get the same data from a .net core rest web api the call to `Http.GetJsonAsync` hangs.  There's no error it just never completes.

```
    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(
            "http://localhost:5000/api/weatherforecast/");
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Flores got me looking in the correct place.

Comment: Also there is an error, I just needed to add an exception handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are running into a CORS issue, because the API and the site are running on a different port.

Comment: you are correct.  Inspecting the console output shows 'no "access-control-allow-origin" header is present …. set the request's mode to no-cors to fetch the resource with CORS disabled'.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to enable Cors, as per [How do you enable cross-origin requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100538/how-do-you-enable-cross-origin-requests-cors-in-asp-net-core-mvc).  Adding a couple of lines to the default web service code did the trick.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // add this
            services.AddCors(); 

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // and this
            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
                       .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: But make sure you add it to `Startup.cs` as well as `StartupJavaScript.cs` if the latter exists, too. That was my problem.